# Is it possible to search a Word document and return all the tables?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, apps-for-office

I want to iterate through all the tables  in a Word document when a user clicks on a button, and change the style of those tables to a predefined style.

Is this possible?

```
Word.run(function(context) {
        var body = context.document.body;

        context.load(body, 'table');

        //iterate through tables

        return context.sync();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The array to iterate is

```
context.document.body.tables.items
```

But you need to load the tables first and sync before you can loop through the tables.items array. Inside your loop you can set various style* properties, font, etc. For details see [Table](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/table).